# How to send newly subscribed email id to admin mail

Tags: magento2

I want to send email of newly subscribed email id to admin mail, I can not send any setting for it in admin please help with it

Comment: so you want to send notification email to admin user on every new subscriptions ?

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: @user1799722, did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be many pre-made modules available for this functionality, but if you want to implement your solution, then you need to create a custom module because Magento does not provide such functionality by default.

I assume that you know how to create a basic module in Magento 2. So skipping to the important ones:

For instance, I am using **Stack** as the package name and **NewsletterNotify** as the module name.

> **Step 1:** Define the email template for your module under **app/code/Stack/NewsletterNotify/etc/email_templates.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="newsletter_subscription_success_admin_email_template" label="Subscription Notification to Admin" file="subscr_notify_admin.html" type="html" module="Stack_NewsletterNotify" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

> **Step 2:** Create a new template under **app/code/Stack/NewsletterNotify/view/frontend/email/subscr_notify_admin.html**.

You can put the content of your choice.

> **Step 3:** Define the observer for your module under **app/code/Stack/NewsletterNotify/etc/frontend/events.xml** and put the following content in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="newsletter_subscriber_save_after">
        <observer name="newsletter_subscriber_save_after_event" instance="Stack\NewsletterNotify\Observer\NotifyAdmin"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

> **Step 4:** Put the observer file **app/code/Stack/NewsletterNotify/Observer/NotifyAdmin.php** with the following content:

```
<?php
namespace Stack\NewsletterNotify\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class NotifyAdmin implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface {
    private $logger;
    private $helper;

    public function __construct(\Stack\NewsletterNotify\Helper\Data $helper, \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger) {
        $this->helper = $helper;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $subscriberEmail = $event->getSubscriber()->getSubscriberEmail();
        $subscriberStatus = $event->getSubscriber()->getSubscriberStatus();
        if ($subscriberStatus == 1) {
            $this->helper->notifyAdmin($subscriberEmail);
        }
    }

}
```

> **Step 5:** Create a helper file **Data.php** under **app/code/Stack/NewsletterNotify/Helper** and put the following content:

```
<?php

namespace Stack\NewsletterNotify\Helper;

class Data {
    protected $_logger;
    protected $_storeManager;
    private $scopeConfig;
    private $transportBuilder;
    private $inlineTranslation;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation, \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder, \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig, \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager, \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger) {

        $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_logger = $logger;
    }

    public function notifyAdmin($email) {
        try {
            $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();

            $this->transportBuilder
                    ->setTemplateIdentifier('newsletter_subscription_success_admin_email_template')
                    ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()])
                    ->setTemplateVars(['subscriber' => $this])
                    ->setFrom(array('email' => '{sender email}', 'name' => '{sender name}'))
                    ->addTo({admin email}, {admin name});
            $transport = $this->transportBuilder->getTransport();
            $transport->sendMessage();

            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->_logger->critical($e->getMessage());
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getStoreId()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore(true)->getId();
    }

}
```

> **Step 6:** Run the following commands:

```
php bin/magento s:up

php bin/magento s:d:c
```

Check the store now.

**Note:** Change the values of **`{admin email}`**, **`{admin name}`**, **`{sender email}`** and **`{sender name}`** before checking.

**Update: Sample content for subscr_notify_admin.html file**

```
<!--@subject {{trans "Subscription Notification to Admin"}} @-->
<!--@vars {
"template config_path=\"design\/email\/footer_template\"":"Email Footer Template",
"template config_path=\"design\/email\/header_template\"":"Email Header Template"
} @-->


{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

{{trans "A new user has subscribed to our newsletter."}}

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

Comment: sorry i just noticed it is giving error : Something went wrong with the subscription.

Comment: What happens if you disable this module?

Comment: sorry it is working please fix wrong template name that was causing issue : subscr_notify_athe dmin.html to be subscr_notify_admin.html

Comment: Changed.. thanks for pointing out the typo mistake :)

Comment: i need one more help , what to put in html file to get subscriber email

Comment: I have added sample content now.

Comment: i want to add content like new subscriber added with email : abc@xyz.com i am unable to get subscriber email varibale in html

Comment: bro please help with it i want to send email in mail copy

Comment: Sorry, I could not update due to busy schedule for last few days. I just saw a new question from you today. I have answered it.